# Excel C# Com Chart Multiple Series Problem

Tags: c#, excel, com, charts, series

Please can someone help me with this as it's driving me nuts!

I'm creating an excel chart using C# and the COM interface pragmatically.

I've created the chart using the chart wizard.

I want to then add more series to this chart. I can add the series but the extra data is on new columns and they are not automatically created.

Am I going about this the wrong way?

Add Chart:

```
public void MakeExcelChart(string startRange, string endRange, string chartTitle, string seriesName)
    {
        ExcelChart = (Excel.Chart)ExcelWBook.Charts.Add(Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
        ExcelApp.Visible = true;
        ExcelChart.HasTitle = true;
        ExcelChart.ChartTitle.Text = chartTitle;

        ExcelRange = ExcelWSheet.get_Range(startRange, endRange);

        ExcelChart.ChartWizard(ExcelRange, Excel.XlChartType.xlColumnClustered, Missing.Value, Excel.XlRowCol.xlColumns, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);

        ExcelChart.ApplyDataLabels(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlDataLabelsType.xlDataLabelsShowBubbleSizes, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);

        ExcelChart.ChartArea.Fill.OneColorGradient(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoGradientStyle.msoGradientHorizontal, 1, 1);

        GetSeriesCollection();

        ExcelSeries = ExcelSeriesCollection.Item(1);
        ExcelSeries.Name = seriesName;
    }
```

And to add series:

```
public void AddSeries(string col1, string col2, string startRange, string endRange, string seriesName)
    {
        ExcelSeries = ExcelSeriesCollection.NewSeries();

        ExcelSeries.HasDataLabels = true;

        ExcelRange = ExcelWSheet.get_Range(col1+startRange, col1+endRange);

        ExcelSeries.XValues = ExcelRange;

        ExcelRange = ExcelWSheet.get_Range(col2+startRange, col2+endRange);

        ExcelSeries.Values = ExcelRange;

        ExcelChart.HasLegend = true;

        ExcelSeries.Name = seriesName;

       }
```

Comment: Also I did already do a search and nothing I could find dealt with multiple series of data on one chart!

Comment: can you please show us how you call your functions. specifically , what values for the startRange, endRange, col1 and col2 variables.

Answer (score 2):

try something like this. It works for me pretty well.

```
Excel.ChartObjects xlChart = (Excel.ChartObjects)xlWorkSheet.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
Excel.ChartObject myChart = (Excel.ChartObject)xlChart.Add(1050, 865, 690, 265);
Excel.Chart chartPage = myChart.Chart;
chartPage.ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xlColumnClustered;
chartPage.HasTitle = true;
chartPage.ChartTitle.Text = "title";
chartPage.HasLegend = true;

Excel.SeriesCollection oSeriesCollection = (Excel.SeriesCollection)myChart.Chart.SeriesCollection(misValue);
Excel.Series series1 = oSeriesCollection.NewSeries();
Excel.Series series2 = oSeriesCollection.NewSeries();
Excel.Series series3 = oSeriesCollection.NewSeries();

Excel.Range series1_range = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("start_range1","end_range1");
Excel.Range series2_range = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("start_range2","end_range2");
Excel.Range series3_range = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("start_range3","end_range3");

series1.Values = series1_range;
series2.Values = series2_range;
series3.Values = series3_range;
```

you can then change parameters of each series individually for example:

```
series1.Name = "some name";
```

and so on.

Comment: how to dynamically create  it using for loop?

Comment: @SaurabhAgrawal You do this in the loop: oSeriesCollection.NewSeries(); chartPage.SeriesCollection(i).Values = ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend the Excel table that is defining the data.
Good example is at
http://blogs.msdn.com/vsod/archive/2009/06/15/creating-charts-in-word-and-powerpoint-using-newly-introduced-object-model-in-office-2007-service-pack-2.aspx